# Stop sending updates to specific groups in signalR

Tags: c#, jquery, web-services, signalr

Problem: 
 I have a groups which are created dynamically based on variable stored in Query string which are send by clients on connection `.start()`

```
  $.connection.hub.qs = "live=" + eventID;
  $.connection.hub.start({ transport: 'longPolling' }).done(function (data) {}
```

I am sending updates to clients every 5 seconds. Those groups “live” certain amount of time. E.g. live betting games. So every game /match is a group. When game ends, I would like to remove that group and stop sending updates to clients which are in that group (force clients in that group to disconnect).
So what happens is, I don't send any new dana to that group I just ignore that group :) , but clients in that group are still sending pending request (in case if long pooling is transport) every 120 seconds or little less they got reposes (which is basically request timeout).

Possible Solutions:

- After reading some posts I concluded that this can be done by keeping those groups (with corresponding `connectionIDs`) in memory as a static field of Hub class, or in data store. And after some match  ends I should remove all `connectionIDs` from that group.
- Maybe I could define one more client (when I say client I think JS client jus to be clear) function which is called when match ends on server. Something like.

  ```
  var myHubProxy = $.connection.myHub
     myHubProxy.client.stopClient = function() {
     $.connection.hub.stop();
  };
  ```

Any help or  suggestion is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second approach is the best one right now. We are investigating adding a feature in a future version that will let you immediately disconnect a client from the server-side.

Comment: => I'm looking forward to new releases with this feature. Thanks for advice.